# Computing Logarithm using homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Let's say we have $Enc_{pub}(a)$, the encryption of an integer $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ under the public key `pub` with a Homomorphic encryption scheme that supports both addition and multiplication.

Is there an efficient way to compute $Enc_{pub}(log(a))$?

I tried with Taylor Series approximation, but this one won't work unless we have the Taylor  series of $log(x)$ about a point $b$ that is very close to $a$, which we cannot afford given that we don't know the value of $a$.

Comment: You could try to compute the hyperbolic arctan instead using an approximation or CORDIC, then use the identity described in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146321/calculate-logarithm-using-vhdl) to translate atanh to the natural log.

Comment: I think that approximating the hyperbolic $arctan$ is the same as approximating $log$, there will be the same issue.  
 As for CORDIC, I didn't go thoroughly into details, but it seems to me that this algorithm is quite costly in terms of needed operations to ensure the convergence.

Comment: This is way off, but functionally speaking when I did enzyme assembly, we'd use the Lambert W function to solve something similar.

Comment: Maybe you can use some techniques from the MPC land. Say you have the encryption of the $a$'s bits: $E(a_0), \dots E(a_k)$ where $k=\log{a}$. Then you can obtain the $2$ base logarithm by taking the most significant bit i.e $E(\max(i \cdot a_i))$ where $a_i=1$. I guess you can extend this to different base logarithms.

Comment: Actually, it would be perfect if I can convert homomorphically $Enc(a)$, to the encryption of every single bit of the value of $a$ expressed in some base $b$

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit messy, but it should work...

If we have access to a fully homomorphic encryption scheme $E(x)$ then we know that $E(x) + E(y) = E(x+y)$ and $E(x) \cdot E(y) = E(x \cdot y)$.

In addition we know that there exists an efficient Boolean circuit, $BC$, such that $BC(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = y_1, y_2,...y_n$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the bits of the binary string $x$ and $y$ respectively both of length $n$ and that $x = b^y$ for some base $b$.  Thus this is the circuit for $\log_b(x) = y$.

Now instead of being given $E(x)$ we can just as easily be given $E(x_1), E(x_2), ..., E(x_n)$.  When you want to encode a $0$ you map it to a random even number, $b$, then you encrypt that number, $E(b)$.  Likewise for $1$, except you map it to an even number.  Now all we do is evaluate the circuit and when we encounter an xor gate we do $E(I_1 \oplus I_2) = E(I_1) + E(I_2)$ and likewise for and gates $E(I_1 \wedge I_2) = E(I_1) \cdot E(I_2)$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the inputs to the gate.  For all other gates convert them into $and$ and $xor$ gates.  At the end we will be left with $E(y_1), E(y_2),...,E(y_n)$ which is an encryption of the $\log_b(x)$.

One interesting benefit is that $x$ and $y$ could be represented in any way, not just a n-bit integer.  You would just need to use the correct circuit for the representation.  For example if $n = 64$ you could let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be the IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format representation of $x$ and with the correct circuit $y_1, y_2,...y_n$ would be a double-precision floating-point so you can do more precise calculations if you wanted.

See [What does "circuits" mean in Cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/what-does-circuits-mean-in-cryptography) for more details on the Boolean circuit only using addition and multiplication.

Edit:

Since the question originally asked how to get from $E(x)$ to $E(log(x))$ and my answer only works if you have the bits and returns bits, I asked another question [Fully Homomorphic Encryption: Going from an integer to bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/fully-homomorphic-encryption-going-from-an-integer-to-bits) to try to help.

They suggested using a Bit Extraction Circuit to go from $E(x)$ to $E(x_1), E(x_2), ..., E(x_n)$.  Then compute the above.  Now you have $E(y_1), E(y_2),...,E(y_n)$ which you can easily put back together by computing (assuming $y_1$ is the least significant bit) $E(log(x)) = E(y_1) + 2\cdot E(y_2) + 2^2\cdot E(y_3)+\dots+2^{n-1}\cdot E(y_n)$

Comment: This solution seems to be efficient, but the context where I'm working does not allow me to provide the encryption of every bit of the message $x$, that's why i should compute $E(log(x))$ otherwise

Comment: I'm wondering if it is possible to go from $E(x)$ to $E(x_1),E(x_2),...,E(x_n)$ using addition and multiplication. So I posted a new question [Fully Homomorphic Encryption: Going from an integer to bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/fully-homomorphic-encryption-going-from-an-integer-to-bits)

Comment: @edggy, are you sure that's how the bitwise addition and multiplication works? I think you need to simulate carries for the addition whereas for multiplication it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Dragos: Look at [Introduction to Homomorphic Encryption](https://www.slideshare.net/chrisma0/introduction-to-homomorphic-encryption). This is a good slideshow describing how to use homomorphic encryption to compute a binary circuit.  Basically you map "0" to even integers and "1" to odd integers.  Then "+" becomes the binary "xor" operator and "$\cdot$" becomes the binary "and" gate.  You can create any logic circuit using only "xor" and "and" gates.

Comment: I see. But I think @Younes was asking how would you implement the binary circuit which gives you bit-decomposed form of the logarithm.

Comment: I know that such a circuit exists, but not what it is.  This is no longer a crypto question, it is an electrical engineering question.  Maybe they have an answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and if not you can ask.  Here are my thoughts. If we are trying to compute $\left \lceil{log(x)}\right \rceil$ then all we need to do is find the index of the leftmost $1$ and return its index.  For example 00000101 should return 00000011 since the leftmost $1$ is in the 3rd position.  I don't know how to construct it, but it shouldn't be too hard.  (Left as an exercise for the reader)