# Fully Homomorphic Encryption: Going from an integer to bits

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I was answering this question [Computing Logarithm using homomorphic encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48514/computing-logarithm-using-homomorphic-encryption) and I came up with a solution if you had encryptions of the bits of the number that you wanted to take the log of.  But in that situation all they have is a fully homomorphic encryption of the number itself.

I was curious if there was a way to compute encryptions of the bits from an encryption of the number.  i.e. is there some $f$ such that $f(E(x)) = (E(x_1),E(x_2),...,E(x_n))$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th bit of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for you is to use a Bit Extraction Circuit. The references are framed in terms of MPC but they should be applicable. If you want something more specific/efficient to homomorphic encryption, it will depend on the scheme.

- [O. Catrina and S. Hoogh, “Improved primitives for secure multiparty
  integer computation,” in Security and Cryptography for Networks
  (SCN’10), ser. LNCS, vol. 6280. Springer, 2010, pp. 182–199.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-15317-4_13)
- [O. Catrina and A. Saxena, “Secure computation with fixed-point
  numbers,” in Financial Cryptography and Data Security (FC’10), ser.
  LNCS, vol. 6052. Springer, 2010, pp. 35–50.](https://ifca.ai/pub/fc10/31_47.pdf)
- [I. Damgard, M. Fitzi, E. Kiltz, J. B. Nielsen, and T. Toft, “Unconditionally secure constant-rounds multi-party computation for equality,
  comparison, bits and exponentiation,” in TCC’06, ser. LNCS, vol. 3876.
  Springer, 2006, pp. 285–304.](https://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2006/38760286/38760286.pdf)